# What could be lowering my ringer volume every day?

Tags: volume-control

I have a new Pixel 3.
Just about every day, I find the volume of the device is quite low.
I turn it up, only to find it on a low (20%) setting the day after.

What could be resetting my volume to this low setting every day?

Comment: don't touch it for 24 hours then check again

Comment: Although not the ringer vol. but in my case i find my media volume gets lowered even i increased it to full yesterday.

Comment: Do you adjust the ring volume by the volume buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is the Insight Timer meditation app.
It switches the phone to Do Not Disturb while a timer is activated, but also for some reason puts it on vibrate (a separate setting) and also lowers the ringer volume. I contacted their support.